# Sigcheck from sysinternals not running in windows container Docker

Tags: docker, sysinternals

I am facing a problem when trying to run inside an interactive command prompt Sigcheck.exe from Sysinternals.
It starts running and shows the banner info like copyright but it looks like it's blocked, it just stays in running state without going further.

I tried running it on my laptop just to show the help and it works.
However, in docker it stops.

Does anyone know what might be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Add the /accepteula command line parameter

Comment: This does not answer the question "Does anyone know what might be the cause?". Suggestion: Provide a full explanation of what caused the problem and why this is a solution, with references if available.

Comment: I ran into the same issue where sigcheck was hanging while run within a docker container.  Adding the /accepteula command line parameter solved the problem.